# Issue with video tag . poster is not visible after video call ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Initially the poster is visible before video call start after video call ends i am able to see a black background in place of poster in video container.

below is the html tag that i have used for this purpose.

```
<div id="videoSmall">
     <video id="videoInput" autoplay width="240px" height="180px" poster="img/webrtc.png"></video>
</div>
```

i have tried to reset "videoInput" div with this code

```
var tag = $("#videoInput").clone();
$("#videoInput").replaceWith(tag);
```

This code works and brings poster image back but the issue with this is when i am performing video call again without refreshing the page  .. the poster is not vanishing in order to show video .

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding **`ended`** eventListener to the video element, and call the video load() again.

**Here is a working example: [CodePEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRqAAZ)**

**HTML:**

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls poster="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3html5.gif">

  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery:**

```
var video= $('#video')[0]; 
var videoNew= $('#video');        
videoNew.on('ended',function(){
    video.load();     
});
```

Comment: Make sure that the video element id in the HTML matches the id in the  jQuery.

Comment: i have also  tried this solution before ..it is not working . also i have individually executed this line  -video.load() in chrome console ; i have noticed the poster is visible for blink of seconds and then it vanishes leaves black background in video container

Comment: var video= $('#videoOutput')[0];                                                                                         and  iam getting this <video id="videoOutput" autoplay="" width="640px" height="480px" poster="./img/webrtc.png" src=""></video> as output in chrome console

Comment: Remove the `autoplay` attribute from video element.

Comment: by removing autoplay attribute video call is not able to take place.

Comment: to check video calling you should need backend ( which is in node js ) and kurento media server. even though i create a codepen you will be not able to execute video

Comment: You can modify it to get the result you want. Basically I've added another div with a background image (the poster image) and made it show on top of video when 'pause'. (once again you can modify it for your needs). 

And again when video ends it fires 'ended' and 'pause' events so the video can load() to the original state and the poster is shown on top of the video element.

Comment: Thanks for reply .. if you are interseted you can check this link https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/blob/master/kurento-one2one-call . still i am facing same issue ..